# Simple logon script

Tags: php, mysql, login-control

I'm trying to do a simple logon script. That is, accept form content through a POST action. Check the database for a matching record. Pull other information from that row such as `Full Name`.

The code I have is;

```
if ( !isset($_POST['loginsubmit']) ) {
    //Show login form
    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
        <p>
            Account ID:
            <input name="AccountID" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Username:
            <input name="userEmail" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>Password:
            <input name="userPassword" type="password" />
        <p>
            <input name="loginsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php
}
else {
    //Form has been submitted, check for logon details
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'accountID'=". $_POST['AccountID']. " AND     'userEmail'=". $_POST['userEmail'] . " AND 'userPassword'=". $_POST['userPassword']. "     LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($count == 1){
        echo"Correct Username/Password";
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
}
```

I have two issues. Firstly with the above code, I keep getting the following error.

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...

Second, how do I get the other details fields out of the databse. I presume

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

contains an array for the MySQL row, so could I do something like;

```
echo $result['fullName'];
```

Comment: FYI, you are **wide open** to SQL injection and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: And your problem on "boolean given" means that you have an error in your SQL query

Comment: i had thought about SQL injection etc and did start with that in my code but i was getting the same error so i stipped it out. I wasn't using PDO though as i hadn't heard about it. I'll have a read up thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sanitize the fields to prevent SQL injection.

```
$sanitize_fields = array('AccountID','userEmail','userPassword'); 
foreach( $sanitize_fields as $k => $v ) 
{
    if( isset( $_POST[ $v ] ) ) 
        $_POST[ $v ] = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST[ $v ] ); 
}
```

Then quote the string fields in your query. Initially there was an error in your query. That's why you were getting a boolean value of false.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE accountID='". $_POST['AccountID']. "' AND userEmail='". $_POST['userEmail'] . "' AND userPassword='". $_POST['userPassword']. "' LIMIT 1";
```

I suggest you do the following after running the query to see the error generated by MySQL, if there is one.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

The MySQL extension is being phased out and there are newer better extensions such as MySQLi and PDO, have a look at those.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'll certainly look into the better extensions.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'accountID'=". $_POST['AccountID']. " AND 'userEmail'=". $_POST['userEmail'] . " AND 'userPassword'=". $_POST['userPassword']. " LIMIT 1";
```

if in the table, the userEmail and userPassword are strings, please add single qoutes:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE accountID=". $_POST['AccountID']. " AND userEmail='". $_POST['userEmail'] . "' AND userPassword='". $_POST['userPassword']. "' LIMIT 1";
```

To get the results:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        echo $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
    }
}
```

Your codes are very insecure:

- Please use [MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi) or [PDO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#History) to interact with the database
- Escape all input data before sending to the database

Comment: When helping somebody with his problem it would be very appreciated If You point out the bad approaches, like not escaping the user input, etc... If You don' know what I am talking about, read also about SQL injection...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    else {
        //Form has been submitted, check for logon details
        $conn = mysql_connect("db-host-here","db-user-here","db-pass-here");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE accountID=". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AccountID']). " AND userEmail='". $_POST['userEmail']=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userEmail']); . "' AND userPassword='".  $_POST['userPassword']=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPassword']);. "' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count == 1){
            echo"Correct Username/Password";
        }
        else {
            echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        }
    }
    // Get other information:

    $dbInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc(); //If more than one row can be selected, use a while loop.

    //Now play with $dbInfo:

    echo $dbInfo['some_other_column'];
```

You have single quotes in your query where you don't need them, and you're missing them where you do. Try the code above.

Replace `db-host-here`,`db-user-here` and `db-password-here` with the correct database information.

I have done some escaping in your code, to prevent injection attacks. But you should really look into using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Your query fails to select any row therefore a boolean `FALSE` is returned from `mysql_query` call.

You should repair Your query and always check if the `$result = mysql_query($query);` returns false or not, like so:

```
// ...
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result !== false) {
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    // ...
}
```

But I recommend using PDO or at least mysqli http://php.net/mysqli.